# MASM 16-Bit Array Addition

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I need to sum 2 separate arrays. One array totals to 243, and I had no issue adding it and storing it in a value. But the second array totals 330 and and since it is a 16bit number I think I have to use dx register instead of dl. However now when I add the numbers the register is set to 0000204A which isn't 330 in decimal format. What am I doing wrong? How do I go about fixing this?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode: DWORD

.data
    AR1 DB 25, 89, 49, 80
    AR2 DB 30, 100, 50, 150
    AR1_SUM DWORD 0   ; variable to store the sum of AR1 elements
    AR2_SUM DWORD 0   ; variable to store the sum of AR2 elements


.code
_main PROC
    
    mov esi, offset AR1 ; set ESI to point to the first element of AR1
    mov ecx, 4 ; reset the loop counter
    xor edx, edx ;

    addloop1:
        add dl, [esi] ; add the current byte to the sum
        add esi, 1 ; move to the next byte in AR1
        loop addloop1 ; repeat until all elements in AR1 have been added
    mov AR1_SUM, edx
    
        mov esi, offset AR2 ; set ESI to point to the first element of AR2
        mov ecx, 4 ; reset the loop counter
        xor edx, edx ; reset the sum register for AR2

        addloop2:
                add dx, [esi] ; add the current byte to the sum
                add esi, 1 ; move to the next byte in AR2
                loop addloop2 ; repeat until all elements in AR2 have been added
        mov AR2_SUM, edx ; store the sum of AR2 in AR2_SUM
    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0

_main ENDP
END _main
```

Comment: Fun fact: `pxor xmm0, xmm0` / `psadbw xmm1, xmm0` can sum unsigned bytes in each half of XMM1 without truncating.  So if you'd loaded XMM1 with SSE4.1 `pmovzxdq xmm1, qword ptr [AR1]`, you could get both your array sums in a couple instructions without looping.  (`movd [AR1_SUM], xmm1` / `pextrd [AR2_SUM], xmm1, 2`, or use `pshufd` / `movq` to do one 8-byte store of both sums.)  But it only works this conveniently because you have exactly 4 bytes in each array.  Still, you can loop 4, 8, or 16 bytes at a time until near the end of larger arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `add dx, [esi]` adds a word not a byte. By specifying `dx` you also increased the implicit size of the array item. There are various ways to fix it. One option is to zero extend into a 16 bit register and do the addition that way, e.g.:

```
movzx ax, [esi]
add dx, ax
```

You could also handle the carry manually, such as:

```
add dl, [esi]
adc dh, 0
```

Comment: Thank you, I followed your second instruction and it worked. I'm fairly new to assembly, how would I go about dividing both of my variables and storing it in a register if the result is 0.73? Then multiplying it by 100 to give me 73?

Comment: You first want to multiply, then divide.